# Upload SSL Certificate file (.pfx) for Azure web app using Azure SDK

Tags: azure, ssl, ssl-certificate, azure-sdk-.net

How can I upload a ".pfx" file (SSL Certificate) for an Azure app service using Azure SDK?

There is a command in [Azure CLI (Certificates - Create Or Update)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/certificates/createorupdate), but I would like to know if there are any features in Azure SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use c# SDK to create SSL certificate, please refer to the following stpes

1. Create a service principal and assign `Contributor` to the sp

```
az login

az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --role contributor \
    --scopes /subscriptions/{SubID} \
    --sdk-auth
```

2. Code

```
string clientId = "<sp appid>";
            string clientSecret = "<sp password>";
            string tenantDomain = "<sp tenant>";
            string subscription = "";
            var creds= SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecret, tenantDomain, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

            var azure= Azure.Configure()
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.BodyAndHeaders)
                .Authenticate(creds)
                .WithSubscription(subscription);

           var res= azure.AppServices.AppServiceCertificates.Define("test")
                .WithRegion(Region.AsiaEast)
                .WithExistingResourceGroup("<group name>")
                .WithPfxFile(@"<pfx file path>")
                .WithPfxPassword("password")
                .Create();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think (not really sure) it's this one

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.appservice.fluent.appservicecertificate.definition.iwithcertificate?view=azure-dotnet