# Problems installing a TLS certificate on an Azure App Service using the latest SDK

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, ssl-certificate, azure-sdk-.net, azure-webapps

*(Note: either a VB.NET or a C# answer will be fine.)*

I'm having trouble installing an uploaded certificate using the [new SDK](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.ResourceManager.AppService/1.0.2/index.html).

I'm using the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/certificates/create-or-update) for the upload, as there doesn't appear to be a way to do that part with the new SDK. Apparently uploading was possible using the older, soon-to-be-deprecated version, as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64311244), but time marches cruelly onward and we must keep up.

The problem is that I'm getting a 404 when I push the update with the new site data:

> Status: 404 (Not Found) - Certificate 370A4097E85476AE65545702B410866882AD4541 was not found.

That thumbprint matches the pfx cert's thumbprint, so we know that that part's working.

I'm getting a 202 for the upload, so that part is working as well. But I would have expected the cert to show up in the portal, which it doesn't. So that's a bit odd.

My full code is below, but for brevity here are the relevant parts:

**Upload**

```vb
oApiCert = New Certificate With {.Location = oWebSiteData.Location.DisplayName}
oApiCert.Properties.CanonicalName = sCanonicalName
oApiCert.Properties.ServerFarmId = oWebSiteData.AppServicePlanId.ToString
oApiCert.Properties.Password = My.Resources.PfxPassword
oApiCert.Properties.PfxBlob = oX509Cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, My.Resources.PfxPassword)
oApiCert.Properties.HostNames.AddRange(oX509Cert.SanHostNames)

sJsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oApiCert, JsonHelper.DefaultSerializationSettings)
oContent = New StringContent(sJsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")

oClient = New HttpClient
oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & oToken.Token)
oClient.BaseAddress = New Uri(My.Resources.ManagementEndpoint)

oResponse = Await oClient.PutAsync(sUrl, oContent)
oResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
```

**Update**

```vb
oSslStates = oWebSiteData.HostNameSslStates

oHostNames = oHostNames.Intersect(oWebSiteData.HostNames).ToList
oHostNames.ForEach(Sub(HostName)
                     oSslState = oSslStates.FirstOrDefault(Function(SslState) SslState.Name = HostName)

                     If oSslState Is Nothing Then
                       oSslState = New HostNameSslState With {.Name = HostName}
                       oSslStates.Add(oSslState)
                     End If

                     oSslState.Thumbprint = BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(oX509Cert.Thumbprint)
                     oSslState.SslState = HostNameBindingSslState.SniEnabled
                     oSslState.ToUpdate = True
                   End Sub)

oSitePatch = New SitePatchInfo

For Each oState In oSslStates
  If oState.ToUpdate Then
    oSitePatch.HostNameSslStates.Add(oState)
  End If
Next

oWebSiteResource.Update(oSitePatch) ' <-- 404 here '
```

This code is ported from the `LetsEncrypt-SiteExtension` package, found [here](https://github.com/sjkp/letsencrypt-siteextension/blob/3eea64e8c1a4582e14df984cce1eae485c219c92/LetsEncrypt.SiteExtension.Core/Services/WebAppCertificateService.cs#L30-L83). That library uses the old SDK.

I'm not necessarily stuck on doing it exactly this way, if there's another way that works. The trouble is that documentation and code samples for the SDK are woefully sparse.

How can I upload and install a third-party TLS certificate on an Azure App Service, using the new SDK? Has anyone found success with this?

**Full Code**

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Azure
Imports Azure.Core
Imports Azure.Identity
Imports Azure.ResourceManager
Imports Azure.ResourceManager.AppService
Imports Azure.ResourceManager.AppService.Models
Imports Azure.ResourceManager.Resources
Imports Matrix.Common
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Nito.AsyncEx

Friend Module Program
  Friend Sub Main()
    AsyncContext.Run(Async Function()
                       Await UploadCert()
                     End Function)
  End Sub



  Private Async Function UploadCert() As Task
    Dim oWebSiteResponse As Response(Of WebSiteResource)
    Dim oWebSiteResource As WebSiteResource
    Dim oResourceGroup As ResourceGroupResource
    Dim sCanonicalName As String
    Dim oSubscription As SubscriptionResource
    Dim oWebSiteData As WebSiteData
    Dim sJsonContent As String
    Dim oCredential As ClientSecretCredential
    Dim oSslStates As IList(Of HostNameSslState)
    Dim oHostNames As List(Of String)
    Dim aHostNames As String()
    Dim oSitePatch As SitePatchInfo
    Dim oArmClient As ArmClient
    Dim oResponse As HttpResponseMessage
    Dim oX509Cert As X509Certificate2
    Dim oSslState As HostNameSslState
    Dim aScopeUrl As String()
    Dim sCertName As String
    Dim oContext As TokenRequestContext
    Dim oContent As StringContent
    Dim oApiCert As Certificate
    Dim oClient As HttpClient
    Dim oToken As AccessToken
    Dim oUrl As List(Of String)
    Dim sUrl As String

    oX509Cert = Utils.GetCertificate(My.Resources.CertFriendlyName)
    aHostNames = My.Resources.HostNames.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    oHostNames = New List(Of String)(aHostNames)
    sCanonicalName = oHostNames.First
    sCertName = $"{sCanonicalName}-{oX509Cert.Thumbprint}"

    oUrl = New List(Of String) From {
      "subscriptions",
      My.Resources.SubscriptionId,
      "resourceGroups",
      My.Resources.ResourceGroup,
      "providers",
      "Microsoft.Web",
      "certificates",
      sCertName
    }

    sUrl = String.Join("/", oUrl)
    sUrl = $"/{sUrl}?api-version=2022-03-01"

    oCredential = New ClientSecretCredential(My.Resources.TenantId, My.Resources.ClientId, My.Resources.ClientSecret)
    oArmClient = New ArmClient(oCredential)
    oSubscription = Await oArmClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync
    oResourceGroup = Await oSubscription.GetResourceGroups.GetAsync(My.Resources.ResourceGroup)
    oWebSiteResponse = Await oResourceGroup.GetWebSiteAsync(My.Resources.AppServiceName)
    oWebSiteResource = oWebSiteResponse.Value
    oWebSiteData = oWebSiteResource.Data
    aScopeUrl = New String() {$"{My.Resources.ManagementEndpoint}.default"}
    oContext = New TokenRequestContext(aScopeUrl)
    oToken = Await oCredential.GetTokenAsync(oContext)

    oApiCert = New Certificate With {.Location = oWebSiteData.Location.DisplayName}
    oApiCert.Properties.CanonicalName = sCanonicalName
    oApiCert.Properties.ServerFarmId = oWebSiteData.AppServicePlanId.ToString
    oApiCert.Properties.Password = My.Resources.PfxPassword
    oApiCert.Properties.PfxBlob = oX509Cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, My.Resources.PfxPassword)
    oApiCert.Properties.HostNames.AddRange(oX509Cert.SanHostNames)

    sJsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oApiCert, JsonHelper.DefaultSerializationSettings)
    oContent = New StringContent(sJsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")

    oClient = New HttpClient
    oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & oToken.Token)
    oClient.BaseAddress = New Uri(My.Resources.ManagementEndpoint)

    oResponse = Await oClient.PutAsync(sUrl, oContent)
    oResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

    oSslStates = oWebSiteData.HostNameSslStates

    oHostNames = oHostNames.Intersect(oWebSiteData.HostNames).ToList
    oHostNames.ForEach(Sub(HostName)
                         oSslState = oSslStates.FirstOrDefault(Function(SslState) SslState.Name = HostName)

                         If oSslState Is Nothing Then
                           oSslState = New HostNameSslState With {.Name = HostName}
                           oSslStates.Add(oSslState)
                         End If

                         oSslState.Thumbprint = BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(oX509Cert.Thumbprint)
                         oSslState.SslState = HostNameBindingSslState.SniEnabled
                         oSslState.ToUpdate = True
                       End Sub)

    oSitePatch = New SitePatchInfo

    For Each oState In oSslStates
      If oState.ToUpdate Then
        oSitePatch.HostNameSslStates.Add(oState)
      End If
    Next

    oWebSiteResource.Update(oSitePatch) ' <-- 404 here '
  End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goodness... *that* sure was an adventure!

OK, after much pain I've hit on the answer. (Side note: it'll be nice to know the SDK equivalent to that [Create/Update Certificate REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/certificates/create-or-update), so I'm still looking...)

The trick (workaround?) is to upload the cert to a Key Vault first, and then from there deploy it to our App Service.

Once the cert is in the vault, all we have to do next is provide four values in the (case-insensitive) JSON body of the PUT call:

1. `.Location` *e.g. East US*
2. `.Properties.KeyVaultSecretName` *the name of the cert in the vault*
3. `.Properties.ServerFarmId` *i.e. AppService.AppServicePlanId.ToString*
4. `.Properties.KeyVaultId` *i.e. KeyVault.Value.Id*

And that's it. No byte array, no password, nothing more than just this.

Except for one other thing... we have to grant the appropriate Access Policies on the vault:

- Our Service Principal = CERTIFICATE IMPORT
- Microsoft Azure App Service principal = SECRET GET

The first is for uploading the cert to the vault and the second is for deployment.

The resource identifier for the Microsoft Azure App Service principal is `abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd`, except for the Azure Gov cloud environment, where it's `6a02c803-dafd-4136-b4c3-5a6f318b4714`.

Like so:

[image]

Upload it to the vault like this:

```vb
Dim oCertClient As CertificateClient
Dim oVaultUri As Uri
Dim oOptions As ImportCertificateOptions
Dim aPfxCert As Byte()

oVaultUri = New Uri($"https://{My.Resources.VaultName}.vault.azure.net")
oCertClient = New CertificateClient(oVaultUri, Credential)

aPfxCert = X509Cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, My.Resources.PfxPassword)
oOptions = New ImportCertificateOptions(CertName, aPfxCert) With {.Password = My.Resources.PfxPassword}

Await oCertClient.ImportCertificateAsync(oOptions)
```

Now we can deploy it to our App Service:

```vb
oApiCert = New Upload.Certificate With {.Location = WebSiteResource.Data.Location.DisplayName}
oApiCert.Properties.KeyVaultSecretName = CertName
oApiCert.Properties.ServerFarmId = WebSiteResource.Data.AppServicePlanId.ToString
oApiCert.Properties.KeyVaultId = oKeyVaultResponse.Value.Id.ToString

aScopeUrls = New String() {$"{My.Resources.ManagementEndpoint}.default"}
oContext = New TokenRequestContext(aScopeUrls)
oToken = Await Credential.GetTokenAsync(oContext)

oHttpClient = New HttpClient
oHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {oToken.Token}")
oHttpClient.BaseAddress = New Uri(My.Resources.ManagementEndpoint)

  ...

sJsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oApiCert, JsonHelper.DefaultSerializationSettings)
oContent = New StringContent(sJsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")

oHttpResponse = Await oHttpClient.PutAsync(sUrl, oContent)
oHttpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
```

I discovered all of this when I stumbled on this [seven-year-old blog post](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2016/05/24/Deploying-Azure-Web-App-Certificate-through-Key-Vault.html) (three cheers for preserving valuable content over the years). Also, here's a [QuickStart Template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.web/web-app-certificate-from-key-vault) for the concept.

One thing that's worth noting about the post: it claims that an unprotected PFX is necessary for this to work. In my testing, however, I've encountered the opposite: for me at least, it works well *with* a password-protected PFX. I'm not going to put any time into trying to figure out that discrepancy; I'm just going to go with it and keep my PFXs protected. So be it. YMMV.

In case it might help someone, here's the full working code:

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Azure
Imports Azure.Core
Imports Azure.Identity
Imports Azure.ResourceManager
Imports Azure.ResourceManager.AppService
Imports Azure.ResourceManager.AppService.Models
Imports Azure.ResourceManager.KeyVault
Imports Azure.ResourceManager.Resources
Imports Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates
Imports Matrix.Common
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Nito.AsyncEx

Friend Module Program
  Friend Sub Main()
    AsyncContext.Run(Async Function()
                       Await InstallNewCert()
                     End Function)
  End Sub

  Private Async Function InstallNewCert() As Task
    Dim oWebSiteResponse As Response(Of WebSiteResource)
    Dim oResourceGroup As ResourceGroupResource
    Dim oSubscription As SubscriptionResource
    Dim oCredential As ClientSecretCredential
    Dim oArmClient As ArmClient
    Dim oX509Cert As X509Certificate2
    Dim sCertName As String

    oCredential = New ClientSecretCredential(My.Resources.TenantId, My.Resources.ClientId, My.Resources.ClientSecret)
    oX509Cert = Utils.GetCertificate(My.Resources.CertFriendlyName)

    sCertName = oX509Cert.SanHostNames.Where(Function(HostName)
                                               Return _
                                                 Not HostName.Contains("*"c) AndAlso
                                                 HostName.Occurs("."c) = 1
                                             End Function).First

    sCertName = sCertName.Split("."c).First
    sCertName = $"{sCertName}-{Guid.NewGuid}"

    oArmClient = New ArmClient(oCredential)
    oSubscription = Await oArmClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync
    oResourceGroup = Await oSubscription.GetResourceGroups.GetAsync(My.Resources.SecondaryResourceGroup)
    oWebSiteResponse = Await oResourceGroup.GetWebSiteAsync(My.Resources.AppServiceName)

    Await UploadCertToVault(oCredential, oX509Cert, sCertName)
    Await DeployCertFromVault(oSubscription, oCredential, oWebSiteResponse.Value, sCertName)
    Await UpdateBindings(oWebSiteResponse.Value, oX509Cert)
  End Function

  Private Async Function UploadCertToVault(
      Credential As ClientSecretCredential,
      X509Cert As X509Certificate2,
      CertName As String) As Task

    Dim oCertClient As CertificateClient
    Dim oVaultUri As Uri
    Dim oOptions As ImportCertificateOptions
    Dim aPfxCert As Byte()

    oVaultUri = New Uri($"https://{My.Resources.VaultName}.vault.azure.net")
    oCertClient = New CertificateClient(oVaultUri, Credential)

    aPfxCert = X509Cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, My.Resources.PfxPassword)
    oOptions = New ImportCertificateOptions(CertName, aPfxCert) With {.Password = My.Resources.PfxPassword}

    Await oCertClient.ImportCertificateAsync(oOptions)
  End Function

  Private Async Function DeployCertFromVault(
      Subscription As SubscriptionResource,
      Credential As ClientSecretCredential,
      WebSiteResource As WebSiteResource,
      CertName As String) As Task

    Dim oKeyVaultResponse As Response(Of KeyVaultResource)
    Dim oResourceGroup As ResourceGroupResource
    Dim oHttpResponse As HttpResponseMessage
    Dim sJsonContent As String
    Dim oHttpClient As HttpClient
    Dim aScopeUrls As String()
    Dim oContext As TokenRequestContext
    Dim oApiCert As Upload.Certificate
    Dim oContent As StringContent
    Dim oToken As AccessToken
    Dim oUrl As List(Of String)
    Dim sUrl As String

    oResourceGroup = Await Subscription.GetResourceGroups.GetAsync(My.Resources.PrimaryResourceGroup)
    oKeyVaultResponse = Await oResourceGroup.GetKeyVaultAsync(My.Resources.VaultName)

    oApiCert = New Upload.Certificate With {.Location = WebSiteResource.Data.Location.DisplayName}
    oApiCert.Properties.KeyVaultSecretName = CertName
    oApiCert.Properties.ServerFarmId = WebSiteResource.Data.AppServicePlanId.ToString
    oApiCert.Properties.KeyVaultId = oKeyVaultResponse.Value.Id.ToString

    aScopeUrls = New String() {$"{My.Resources.ManagementEndpoint}.default"}
    oContext = New TokenRequestContext(aScopeUrls)
    oToken = Await Credential.GetTokenAsync(oContext)

    oHttpClient = New HttpClient
    oHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {oToken.Token}")
    oHttpClient.BaseAddress = New Uri(My.Resources.ManagementEndpoint)

    oUrl = New List(Of String) From {
      "subscriptions",
      My.Resources.SubscriptionId,
      "resourceGroups",
      My.Resources.PrimaryResourceGroup,
      "providers",
      "Microsoft.Web",
      "certificates",
      CertName
    }

    sUrl = String.Join("/", oUrl)
    sUrl = $"/{sUrl}?api-version=2022-03-01"

    sJsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oApiCert, JsonHelper.DefaultSerializationSettings)
    oContent = New StringContent(sJsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")

    oHttpResponse = Await oHttpClient.PutAsync(sUrl, oContent)
    oHttpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
  End Function

  Private Async Function UpdateBindings(
      WebSiteResource As WebSiteResource,
      X509Cert As X509Certificate2) As Task

    Dim oSslStates As IList(Of HostNameSslState)
    Dim oSitePatch As SitePatchInfo
    Dim oSslState As HostNameSslState

    oSslStates = WebSiteResource.Data.HostNameSslStates
    oSitePatch = New SitePatchInfo

    With X509Cert.SanHostNames.Intersect(WebSiteResource.Data.HostNames).ToList
      .ForEach(Sub(HostName)
                 oSslState = oSslStates.FirstOrDefault(Function(SslState) SslState.Name = HostName)

                 If oSslState Is Nothing Then
                   oSslState = New HostNameSslState With {.Name = HostName}
                   oSslStates.Add(oSslState)
                 End If

                 oSslState.Thumbprint = BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(X509Cert.Thumbprint)
                 oSslState.SslState = HostNameBindingSslState.SniEnabled
                 oSslState.ToUpdate = True
               End Sub)
    End With

    For Each oState In oSslStates
      If oState.ToUpdate Then
        oSitePatch.HostNameSslStates.Add(oState)
      End If
    Next

    Await WebSiteResource.UpdateAsync(oSitePatch)
  End Function
End Module
```