# How to create or update a certificate using the latest SDK

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, ssl-certificate, azure-sdk-.net, azure-webapps

Does anyone know what the SDK equivalent to [this REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/certificates/create-or-update) is? Unfortunately, the SDK is so poorly documented that—after two full days of digging—I finally have to ask.

My prior research and things I've tried are detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76287757).

Comment: Did you happen to check  this SO thread answers-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64306380/upload-ssl-certificate-file-pfx-for-azure-web-app-using-azure-sdk and the samples here- https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/AppServiceCertificate/-/php-appservicecertificate-class-examples.html

Comment: I did, yes, but those are from the old (soon-to-be-deprecated) SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to Create or Update the Certificate with SDK you can refer this [**Github sample**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/websites/Azure.ResourceManager.AppService/samples/Generated/Samples/Sample_AppCertificateCollection.cs) of ***Latest Azure.ResourceManager.AppService .Net sample***.

Code from the [github sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/websites/Azure.ResourceManager.AppService/samples/Generated/Samples/Sample_AppCertificateCollection.cs) above:-

> ```cs
> // Create Or Update Certificate
>         [NUnit.Framework.Test]
>         [NUnit.Framework.Ignore("Only verifying that the sample builds")]
>         public async Task CreateOrUpdate_CreateOrUpdateCertificate()
>         {
>             // Generated from example definition: specification/web/resource-manager/Microsoft.Web/stable/2021-02-01/examples/CreateOrUpdateCertificate.json
>             // this example is just showing the usage of "Certificates_CreateOrUpdate" operation, for the dependent resources,
> they will have to be created separately.
>
>             // get your azure access token, for more details of how Azure SDK get your access token, please refer to
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication?tabs=command-line
>             TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
>             // authenticate your client
>             ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);
>
>             // this example assumes you already have this ResourceGroupResource created on azure
>             // for more information of creating ResourceGroupResource, please refer to the document of ResourceGroupResource
>             string subscriptionId = "xxxxsubidxxxx";
>             string resourceGroupName = "rgname";
>             ResourceIdentifier resourceGroupResourceId = ResourceGroupResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId,
> resourceGroupName);
>             ResourceGroupResource resourceGroupResource = client.GetResourceGroupResource(resourceGroupResourceId);
>
>             // get the collection of this AppCertificateResource
>             AppCertificateCollection collection = resourceGroupResource.GetAppCertificates();
>
>             // invoke the operation
>             string name = "certname";
>             AppCertificateData data = new AppCertificateData(new AzureLocation("East US"))
>             {
>                 Password = "<password>",
>                 HostNames = { "ServerCert" },
>             };
>             ArmOperation<AppCertificateResource> lro = await collection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, name, data);
>             AppCertificateResource result = lro.Value;
>
>             // the variable result is a resource, you could call other operations on this instance as well
>             // but just for demo, we get its data from this resource instance
>             AppCertificateData resourceData = result.Data;
>             // for demo we just print out the id
>             Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded on id: {resourceData.Id}");
>         }
>     } 
>     }
> ```

Complete code to manage Certificates of App Service:-

> ```cs
> using Azure.Core; using Azure.Identity; using Azure.ResourceManager;
> using Azure.ResourceManager.AppService; using
> Azure.ResourceManager.Resources; using NUnit;
>
>
>
> namespace Azure.ResourceManager.AppService.Samples {
>     public partial class Sample_AppCertificateCollection
>     {
>         static void Main(string[] args)
>         {
>         }
>         // List Certificates by resource group
>         [NUnit.Framework.Test]
>         [NUnit.Framework.Ignore("Only verifying that the sample builds")]
>         public async Task GetAll_ListCertificatesByResourceGroup()
>         {
>             // Generated from example definition: specification/web/resource-manager/Microsoft.Web/stable/2021-02-01/examples/ListCertificatesByResourceGroup.json
>             // this example is just showing the usage of "Certificates_ListByResourceGroup" operation, for the dependent
> resources, they will have to be created separately.
>
>             // get your azure access token, for more details of how Azure SDK get your access token, please refer to
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication?tabs=command-line
>             TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
>             // authenticate your client
>             ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);
>
>             // this example assumes you already have this ResourceGroupResource created on azure
>             // for more information of creating ResourceGroupResource, please refer to the document of ResourceGroupResource
>             string subscriptionId = "0151c365-f598-44d6-b4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7";
>             string resourceGroupName = "siliconrg";
>             ResourceIdentifier resourceGroupResourceId = ResourceGroupResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId,
> resourceGroupName);
>             ResourceGroupResource resourceGroupResource = client.GetResourceGroupResource(resourceGroupResourceId);
>
>             // get the collection of this AppCertificateResource
>             AppCertificateCollection collection = resourceGroupResource.GetAppCertificates();
>
>             // invoke the operation and iterate over the result
>             await foreach (AppCertificateResource item in collection.GetAllAsync())
>             {
>                 // the variable item is a resource, you could call other operations on this instance as well
>                 // but just for demo, we get its data from this resource instance
>                 AppCertificateData resourceData = item.Data;
>                 // for demo we just print out the id
>                 Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded on id: {resourceData.Id}");
>             }
>
>             Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded");
>         }
>
>         // Get Certificate
>         [NUnit.Framework.Test]
>         [NUnit.Framework.Ignore("Only verifying that the sample builds")]
>         public async Task Get_GetCertificate()
>         {
>             // Generated from example definition: specification/web/resource-manager/Microsoft.Web/stable/2021-02-01/examples/GetCertificate.json
>             // this example is just showing the usage of "Certificates_Get" operation, for the dependent resources, they will
> have to be created separately.
>
>             // get your azure access token, for more details of how Azure SDK get your access token, please refer to
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication?tabs=command-line
>             TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
>             // authenticate your client
>             ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);
>
>             // this example assumes you already have this ResourceGroupResource created on azure
>             // for more information of creating ResourceGroupResource, please refer to the document of ResourceGroupResource
>             string subscriptionId = "0151c365-f598-44d6-b4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7";
>             string resourceGroupName = "siliconrg";
>             ResourceIdentifier resourceGroupResourceId = ResourceGroupResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId,
> resourceGroupName);
>             ResourceGroupResource resourceGroupResource = client.GetResourceGroupResource(resourceGroupResourceId);
>
>             // get the collection of this AppCertificateResource
>             AppCertificateCollection collection = resourceGroupResource.GetAppCertificates();
>
>             // invoke the operation
>             string name = "certsilicon";
>             AppCertificateResource result = await collection.GetAsync(name);
>
>             // the variable result is a resource, you could call other operations on this instance as well
>             // but just for demo, we get its data from this resource instance
>             AppCertificateData resourceData = result.Data;
>             // for demo we just print out the id
>             Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded on id: {resourceData.Id}");
>         }
>
>         // Get Certificate
>         [NUnit.Framework.Test]
>         [NUnit.Framework.Ignore("Only verifying that the sample builds")]
>         public async Task Exists_GetCertificate()
>         {
>             // Generated from example definition: specification/web/resource-manager/Microsoft.Web/stable/2021-02-01/examples/GetCertificate.json
>             // this example is just showing the usage of "Certificates_Get" operation, for the dependent resources, they will
> have to be created separately.
>
>             // get your azure access token, for more details of how Azure SDK get your access token, please refer to
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication?tabs=command-line
>             TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
>             // authenticate your client
>             ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);
>
>             // this example assumes you already have this ResourceGroupResource created on azure
>             // for more information of creating ResourceGroupResource, please refer to the document of ResourceGroupResource
>             string subscriptionId = "0151c365-f598-44d6-b4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7";
>             string resourceGroupName = "siliconrg";
>             ResourceIdentifier resourceGroupResourceId = ResourceGroupResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId,
> resourceGroupName);
>             ResourceGroupResource resourceGroupResource = client.GetResourceGroupResource(resourceGroupResourceId);
>
>             // get the collection of this AppCertificateResource
>             AppCertificateCollection collection = resourceGroupResource.GetAppCertificates();
>
>             // invoke the operation
>             string name = "certsilicon";
>             bool result = await collection.ExistsAsync(name);
>
>             Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded: {result}");
>         }
>
>         // Create Or Update Certificate
>         [NUnit.Framework.Test]
>         [NUnit.Framework.Ignore("Only verifying that the sample builds")]
>         public async Task CreateOrUpdate_CreateOrUpdateCertificate()
>         {
>             // Generated from example definition: specification/web/resource-manager/Microsoft.Web/stable/2021-02-01/examples/CreateOrUpdateCertificate.json
>             // this example is just showing the usage of "Certificates_CreateOrUpdate" operation, for the dependent resources,
> they will have to be created separately.
>
>             // get your azure access token, for more details of how Azure SDK get your access token, please refer to
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication?tabs=command-line
>             TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
>             // authenticate your client
>             ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);
>
>             // this example assumes you already have this ResourceGroupResource created on azure
>             // for more information of creating ResourceGroupResource, please refer to the document of ResourceGroupResource
>             string subscriptionId = "0151c365-f598-44d6-b4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7";
>             string resourceGroupName = "siliconrg";
>             ResourceIdentifier resourceGroupResourceId = ResourceGroupResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId,
> resourceGroupName);
>             ResourceGroupResource resourceGroupResource = client.GetResourceGroupResource(resourceGroupResourceId);
>
>             // get the collection of this AppCertificateResource
>             AppCertificateCollection collection = resourceGroupResource.GetAppCertificates();
>
>             // invoke the operation
>             string name = "certsilicon";
>             AppCertificateData data = new AppCertificateData(new AzureLocation("East US"))
>             {
>                 Password = "password",
>                 HostNames = { "ServerCert" },
>             };
>             ArmOperation<AppCertificateResource> lro = await collection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, name, data);
>             AppCertificateResource result = lro.Value;
>
>             // the variable result is a resource, you could call other operations on this instance as well
>             // but just for demo, we get its data from this resource instance
>             AppCertificateData resourceData = result.Data;
>             // for demo we just print out the id
>             Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded on id: {resourceData.Id}");
>         }
>     } }
> ```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. That's quite a collection of samples that's hidden away in a dark corner—too bad neither the documentation nor the main page link to there. It's worth noting that this part of the SDK can't be used to deploy a PFX cert directly—it has to be uploaded to a key vault first, and then deployed from there. The sample code only hints at how to do the deployment; I've added another answer showing that.

Answer (score 0):

As I indicated in [the answer to my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76308973), a bring-your-own PFX cert to be used in an App Service Custom Domain binding has to be uploaded to a key vault first. Only then can it be deployed to the App Service certificate pool.

The sample code results in a managed cert, not a PFX cert, and managed certs don't support wildcards. If wildcard isn't a requirement, no problem. Proceed with caution, but proceed.

But if one *is* needed, here's how to push the cert from a vault to the PFX list for use in a binding:

```vb
Private Async Function DeployCertFromVault(Params As DeployParams) As Task
  Dim oCertificateCollection As AppCertificateCollection
  Dim oKeyVaultResponse As Response(Of KeyVaultResource)
  Dim oResourceGroup As Response(Of ResourceGroupResource)
  Dim oCertificate As AppCertificateData

  oResourceGroup = Await Params.Subscription.GetResourceGroups.GetAsync(My.Resources.PrimaryResourceGroup)
  oKeyVaultResponse = Await oResourceGroup.Value.GetKeyVaultAsync(My.Resources.VaultName)
  oCertificateCollection = oResourceGroup.Value.GetAppCertificates

  oCertificate = New AppCertificateData(Params.WebSiteResource.Data.Location) With {
    .KeyVaultSecretName = Params.CertName,
    .ServerFarmId = Params.WebSiteResource.Data.AppServicePlanId,
    .KeyVaultId = oKeyVaultResponse.Value.Id
  }

  Await oCertificateCollection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, Params.CertName, oCertificate)
End Function

Public Structure DeployParams
  Public WebSiteResource As WebSiteResource
  Public Subscription As SubscriptionResource
  Public CertName As String
End Structure
```

Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76308973) for the rest of it.