# Upload a PFX SSL certificate to Azure App Service Web App using Azure SDK

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I'm trying to upload a PFX SSL certificate to Azure App Service Web App using Azure SDK.NET. I have [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64306380/upload-ssl-certificate-file-pfx-for-azure-web-app-using-azure-sdk) but it uses the deprecated Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent package.
I couldn't find any comprehensive sample or example anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Following Nuget Packages in csproj:

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.ResourceManager" Version="1.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.ResourceManager.AppService" Version="1.0.2" />
```

Then you can use code below

```cs
using Azure;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.AppService;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;

var region = "eastus";
string resourceGroupName = "myResourceGroup";
string appServicePlanName = "myAppServicePlan";
string certificateName = "myAppCertificate";
string certPath = @"path_to_certificate.pfx";
string certPassword = "your_cert_password";

// Read PFX
byte[] pfxByteArray;
using (var stream = new FileStream(certPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    pfxByteArray = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(pfxByteArray, 0, (int)stream.Length);
}

ArmClient client = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());

SubscriptionResource subscription = client.GetSubscriptionResource(new Azure.Core.ResourceIdentifier("/subscriptions/aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee"));
ResourceGroupCollection resourceGroups = subscription.GetResourceGroups();
ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup = await resourceGroups.GetAsync(resourceGroupName);
var appServicePlan = await resourceGroup.GetAppServicePlanAsync(appServicePlanName);
var appCertificatesCollection = resourceGroup.GetAppCertificates();
AppCertificateData appCertificate = new AppCertificateData(region)
{
    Password = certPassword,
    PfxBlob = pfxByteArray,
    ServerFarmId = appServicePlan.Value.Id
};

appCertificatesCollection.CreateOrUpdate(WaitUntil.Completed, certificateName, appCertificate);

Console.ReadLine();
```

For More information you can refer to

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.ResourceManager.AppService_1.0.2/doc/dev/mgmt_quickstart.md

And

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.appservice?view=azure-dotnet

Hope this helps. Please replace the variables for your environment.

Comment: The above code is very helpful, however when I pass something in "certificateName " parameter I got an error says that the resource name provided is not found. Should I create it first?
I can check that there is an existing certificate with the same domain name in the Web App certificates, and when I try to delete I got an error says that it can't be delete because it's associated with a domain.
So, if I'm able to delete the custom domain binding I can replace the certificate based on the existing resource